# How much is a safe amount to prove financial solvency while applying for Schengen Visa

Tags: visas, schengen, applications, finland

A Schengen visa application requires personal bank statement, credit card statement covering the last six months as proof of solvency. My question is what could be a safe amount to show financial solvency?

I have about 10,000 USD; is this a safe amount?

Comment: Please take note of the explanations in [Should I submit bank statements when applying for a UK Visa? What do they say about me?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/66104/should-i-submit-bank-statements-when-applying-for-a-uk-visa-what-do-they-say-ab) -- the UK and Schengen regimes are similar enough that the general advice there is also relevant for you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Schengen states have two **different** financial requirements.

- Do you have enough money on hand to cover your expenditures during the trip? [Finland requires a minimum of EUR 30 per day](http://formin.finland.fi/public/default.aspx?nodeid=49459&contentlan=2), so you have more than enough in this regard.
- Do you have an income, expenditures, and assets that make it seem *credible* that you are a tourist or business traveler, and not an illegal immigrant?

As Henning pointed out in his comment, for the second question your monthly flow of income and expenditure are important. If USD 10,000 or even more simply show up in your account, that does not help. If you can save a few hundred USD *each month* from your well-documented income, much less than USD 10,000 should be enough. That's because it is *credible* that a young man would save the disposable income for a couple of months and then go on a holiday trip, that's what young people do.